# Where am I going wrong with this second for loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a taylor weighted beam pattern from his equations in a book. Everything calculates correctly up to a certain point but the values for taylor denom are re used instead of recalculated. This is what I have:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

int main ()
{
double sidelobeRatio, nbar, zeros, wave, length;

cout << "Please enter side lobe ratio, nbar, number of zeros less than or equal to nbar, the wavelength and length of the array." << endl;

cin >> sidelobeRatio >> nbar >> zeros >> wave >> length;

vector<double> DbValues;

double taylorA = 1/M_PI * acosh(pow(10,sidelobeRatio/20));  //Calculates the value of A for sigma and Zn (step 1b)

double sigma = nbar/pow(pow(taylorA,2)+pow((nbar-0.5),2),0.5);  //Calculates the sigma constant for taylor weighting (step 2)

double Zn = sigma * pow(pow(taylorA,2)+pow((zeros-.5),2),(0.5));  //The Zn constant for taylor weighting (step 3)

for (double u=-90; u<=90; u=u + 45)
    {
        double z = (sin(u*M_PI/180)*length) / wave;  //Calculates z for taylor weighting constant (step 1a)

        double taylorSine = sin(M_PI*z)/(M_PI*z);  //The sinc function for beamforming (step 4a)
        cout << taylorSine << " this is taylor sine" << endl;

        double taylorNumerator = 1-pow((z/Zn),2); //The numerator for the taylor weight constant (step 4b)
        cout << taylorNumerator << " this is numerator" << endl;

        double newValue = 1;

        vector<double> newValues;

        for (int zeros=1; zeros <= nbar-1; zeros++)
            {
                double taylorDenom = 1-pow((z/zeros),2);  //The denomenator for the taylor weight constant (step 4c)

                double taylorValue = taylorSine*(taylorNumerator/taylorDenom);  //The taylor equation with capital pi operand (step 5)

                newValue *= taylorValue;

                newValues.push_back(newValue);

                cout << taylorValue << " this is taylorValue" << endl;
            }
        int i;
        for (i=0; i < newValues.size(); i++)
            {
                double convert = 10*log10(pow(newValues[i],2));  //converts F from linear to Db (step 6)

                DbValues.push_back(convert);
            }
        double j;
        for (j=0; j < DbValues.size(); j++)
            {
             cout << DbValues[j] <<endl;
            }
         cout << DbValues.size() << " this is DbValue" << endl;
         cout << newValues.size() << " this is newValue" << endl;
     }
return 0;
};
```

outputs:

```
         -3.89817e-17 this is taylor sine
         -3 this is numerator
         -1.18126e-18 this is taylorValue
         -4.87271e-18 this is taylorValue
         -1.1566e-17 this is taylorValue
         -2.22753e-17 this is taylorValue
         -358.553
         -704.798
         -1043.53
         -1376.58
         4 this is DbValue
         4 this is newValue
         -nan this is taylor sine
         1 this is numerator
         -nan this is taylorValue
         -nan this is taylorValue
         -nan this is taylorValue
         -nan this is taylorValue
         -358.553
         -704.798
         -1043.53
         -1376.58
         -nan
         -nan
         -nan
         -nan
         8 this is DbValue
         4 this is newValue
        -3.89817e-17 this is taylor sine
        -3 this is numerator
        -1.18126e-18 this is taylorValue
        -4.87271e-18 this is taylorValue
        -1.1566e-17 this is taylorValue
        -2.22753e-17 this is taylorValue
        -358.553
        -704.798
        -1043.53
        -1376.58
        -nan
        -nan
        -nan
        -nan
        -358.553
        -704.798
        -1043.53
        -1376.58
        12 this is DbValue
        4 this is newValue
```

expected outputs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEkyn.png)

For each new z that is calculated a new taylor denom needs to be calculated but for some reason I get the same taylor denoms over and over. If something needs more clarification please let me know.

Clarification: when u = 90 degrees, if the user input an nbar of 5, taylor denom needs to be calculated 5 times with that z and n going from 1 to nbar-1. This isn't happening, maybe a while loop needs to be introduced?

I have printed sigma, Zn and taylorA and those calculate correct. The size print outs at the end are always correct. The values in them are not.

inputs:
Ratio: 30     nbar: 5     zeros: 5     wavelength: .1      length: 1

Comment: please include input, output and expected output. Just a guess: is it possible that starting at a certain point the calculation of `taylorDenom` overflows? DId you inspect the values of `taylorDenom` and `taylorValue` before you calculate the product?

Comment: When i put expected inputs it puts it all on one line and it bleeds together.

Comment: -336.5660
-124.7323
-112.6910
-105.6473
-100.6497
-96.7732
-93.6059
-90.9278
-88.6080
-86.5617
-84.7313
-83.0753
-81.5636
-80.1729
-78.8852
-77.6864
-76.5650
-75.5116
-74.5183
-73.5788
-72.6874
-71.8395
-71.0310

Comment: Those are a few expected outputs. Those were done in excel and its a step value of u= u+0.1 instead of 90 as I have. I have 90 to reduce my data points for irght now. The excel goes from -330 to 0 back to -330. Mine only increases

Comment: `for (double u = -90; u <= 90; u = u + 45)` loops `-90, -45, 0, 45, 90`. Where `z = sin (u * M_PI / 180.) ...` will be `0` at `0` making  `taylorSine = sin(M_PI*z)/(M_PI*z);` `inf` if the floating point exception is caught. Then `double taylorDenom = 1-pow((z/zeros),2);` is `0` blowing up `(taylorNumerator / taylorDenom)`. Further, `zeros` in `double sidelobeRatio, nbar, zeros...` conflicts with `for (int zeros = 1; zeros <= nbar - 1; zeros++)` in that the second `int zeros` shadows the original. There are likely problems with your equations as well.

Answer (score 0):

remove the int i; and put it inside the loop.

```
    for (int i=0; i < newValues.size(); i++)
        {
            double convert = 10*log10(pow(newValues[i],2));  //converts F from linear to Db (step 6)

            DbValues.push_back(convert);
        }
```